# How to debug released connections with Spring Webflux and Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-webflux

When using Spring webflux with `Mono` or `Flux` return type, the http connecting thread is parked/released while the connection waits for the response. Thus, the connection is not taking `max-connections`.

Question: how can I test/proof that the connection is really released while waiting for the response, and not blocking max-connections?

I already enabled `DEBUG` logging, but that did not show anything regarding this question.

```
@RestController
public class MyServlet {
   @GetMapping("/")
   public Mono<String>/Flux<String> test() {
       return Mono.just(service.blocking());
   }
}

@Service
public class SlowService {
    public String blocking() {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

Or is that incorrect at all, and I'd have to use:

```
Mono.fromCallable(() -> service.blocking()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
```

But still, how can I see from the logs that the connection gets parked correctly?

To test, I'm using `server.tomcat.max-threads=5`. I'm trying to rewrite my blocking service so that those threads are not blocked during the sleep, and thus more than 5 connections can reach my service concurrently.

Comment: your question is not clear, what to you mean `connection` a client subscribing to your service, or your service calling another service?

Comment: Excuse me, I mean a client connection to my webservice. By default, tomcat has a thread connection limit of I think `100`.

Comment: load test it....

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 thread pools, the forkjoin pool that will handle all the regular work. Then you have the Schedular pool that will handle scheduled tasks.

```
return Mono.just(service.blocking());
```

This will block one of the threads in the ForkJoinPool so less events can be handled by webflux hence slowing down your service.

```
Mono.fromCallable(() -> service.blocking()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
```

This will assign the task and "offload" it to the scheduler pool of threads so another thread pool will handle this and not hog one of the ForkJoinPool threads.

How to test this? You need to load test your service, or as most people do, trust the framework to do what it is set out to do and trust that the spring team has tested their side of things.